# rails uniqueness of on foreign key with scope on date of created_at column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

rails uniqueness of on foreign key with scope on date of created_at column

```
validates :test_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => Date(:created_at)}
```

The above code wont work. But, I need similar thing to validate uniqueness on foreign key with `Date(:created_at)`.

Comment: `validates_uniqueness_of :test_id, conditions: -> { where.("DATE(created_at) != ?", Date.today) }` will work.. check please

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom validation, there's no way to do this with the built-in uniqueness validator.

This one works both with creating new entries, and saving existing ones (by using an existing `created_at` if it's there, otherwise we fall back to `Date.current` which is the timezone-aware way of getting "today":

```
validate :check_test_id

def check_test_id
  date = ( created_at || Date.current ).to_date
  if self.class.exists? ["DATE(created_at) = DATE(?) AND test_id = ?", date, test_id]
    errors.add :test_id, "is not unique for #{date}"
  end
end
```